# Rewrite $ x\sqrt{1-y^2/x^2} = \text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2-y^2} $

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to coax *Mathematica* into rewriting $ x\sqrt{1-y^2/x^2} = \text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2-y^2} $ for $ x $ and $ y $ real. I have tried all combinations of `FullSimplify` and `Refine` with the appropriate assumptions. *Mathematica* refuses to cooperate.

With the additional assumption $ x>0 $, I can get *Mathematica* to simplify to $ \sqrt{x^2-y^2} $, but I don't want to assume this. I want the general result with the $ \text{sgn}(x) $.

Comment: Sometimes, it is actually hard to tell if one form is simpler than another. But if `*Simplify` etc. refuse to carry out further transformations, that means, *Mathematica* determines, according to its own built-in principles, that the "simplest" form has already been reached.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular expression you can use

```
ComplexExpand[Re[x Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2]], {x, y}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, 
    FunctionDomain[x Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2], {x, y}, Reals]] & // ExpandAll

(*Sqrt[x^2 - y^2] Sign[x]*)
```

You can also use `TargetFunctions` with `Sign` or `RealSign` as an option to `ComplexExpand` for more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear, why do you need to make such a replacement by Mathematica, when it is much faster to straightforwardly type the desired expression.

However, if you are insisting, try this

```
expr = x*Sqrt[1 - y^2/x^2];
expr1 = expr /. x -> Sign[z]*Abs[z]

(*  Abs[z] Sqrt[1 - y^2/(Abs[z]^2 Sign[z]^2)] Sign[z]  *)
```

and then

```
(expr1 // Simplify[#, z ∈ Reals && z != 0] &) /. z -> x

(*  Sqrt[x^2 - y^2] Sign[x]  *)
```

Done. Have fun!

Comment: I just gave a simplified example for the purposes of asking the question. I don't need to simplify *this* expression in particular. I need to be able to give Mathematica an expression of unknown form and allow it to perform the simplification using $\text{sgn}$, if it's possible.

Comment: So, I gave you an example. There are, however, several methods. One chooses the  best one according to the expression.